# unix - how to deal with too many args for cat

Tags: unix, arguments, cat

I have a bunch of files in a directory, each with one line of text. I want to cat all of these files together (all the one liners) into a single, large file. However, when I use `cat` there are too many arguments. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
bash$ (ls | xargs cat) > /tmp/some_big_file
```

Answer (score 4):

try to use -n with xargs to reduce the number of arguments passed to cat

```
find .|xargs -n 100 cat >> out
```

Answer (score 2):

look into `xargs`

```
find . <whatever> | xargs cat > outfile.txt
```

Replace the `find . <whatever>` bit with your own way of getting all the files

Replace outfile.txt with your output file.